# match the data with regexp and reverse lookahead if possible

Tags: json, regex

i have this bunch of data:

`{"data":[12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90,10], "something": {"key":"value"}}`

i would like to match everything but integers inside the array, so, when i perform a replace, i would get:

`12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90,10`

is it possible to do this using a reverse lookahead regexp?
or, what should i use to achieve the result?

i'm trying with the following, but it doesn't work: `(?!\d{2},).*`

thank you for your help!

Comment: Why are you trying to use a regex instead of just parse the JSON to an object and access the `data` property?

Comment: i could do this actually, but i have a lot of data like that and likely a regular expression performs it better, anyway i was curious if there was a way

Comment: Beware that regexes are very useful, but not necessary the most performant tool when it comes to huge amounts of text, some patterns can even perform particularly bad as it sometimes has to try huge amounts of substrings to find a match. I recommend you try a benchmark of both solutions

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely use a JSON parsing library here, like GSON, if at all possible.

```
String json = "{\"data\":[12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90,10], \"something\": {\"key\":\"value\"}}";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject rootObj = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray dataArr = rootObj.getAsJsonArray("data");
System.out.println(dataArr);
```

If, for some reason, you really *can't* do something like the above, then here is a one-liner which should work for your input string:

```
String input = "{\"data\":[12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90,10], \"something\": {\"key\":\"value\"}}";
String nums = input.replaceAll(".*\"data\":\\[(.*?)\\].*", "$1");
System.out.println(nums);
```

This prints:

```
12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90,10
```

Comment: Maybe you should state that your answer's examples are in Java, as the OP doesn't precise which language is used

Comment: @Kaddath LOL ... I misread the `json` tag for `Java`.  Guess I'm getting old.

Comment: I know the feel :D

Comment: The regex solution (which should be avoided) is generic, and can be used in any language.

Comment: Indeed, I was only suggesting to add the language used, just a detail

Comment: i don't feel so old, anyway :)
yeah i kept it generic because i bet on a regexp solution, which i guess it's faster on lots of data, but maybe i'm wrong.
why do you say they should be avoided? i see a reverse lookahead doesn't work here: that's because i'd like to apply it for the replace function on visual studio code editor

Comment: You don't need lookarounds here.  Check what I am doing in the second part of my answer with a regex based solution.

Comment: @blurstream they should be avoided in case of JSON in code mostly for robustness, regexes look for particular patterns that can easily break the day someone decide to refactor slightly your data (example: if you add an array in `data`'s array with proposed regex). Parsing the JSON and getting your property will work whatever the structure behind it is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with:

```
(?!\d{2},).*
```

Is that once it finds a position where the next characters do not patch `\d{2},` so that the negative lookahead assertion succeeds, then `.*` matches the rest of the input and you end up replacing the entire string presumably with ''.

So, you can only really afford to safely match one character for replacement with that negative looakahead assertion methodolgy:

```
(?!\d{2},).
```

But what happens now when you the regex engine's current scan position has advanced and is now within the string thus:

```
... [1 2,3 ....
      ^
current position between the 1 and the 2
```

The problem now is that the negative lookahead assertion succeeds because there is not *two* digits but only *one* digit following and so the `2` will be replaced. So if you are to use your methodology, you would have to relax your negative lookahead assertion to:

```
(?!,?\d{1,2},?).
```

In Python:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?!,?\d{1,2},?).', '', '{"data":[12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90,10], "something": {"key":"value"}}')
'12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90,10'
```

But while the regex works for this specific input, it was forced to relax the assertion to such an extent that it would also accept single-digit numbers:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?!,?\d{1,2},?).', '', '{"data":[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0], "something": {"key":"value"}}')
'1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0'
```

So, if you insist on using a regex, an alternate approach to replacing what you don't want is to search for what you do want. For example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\[)\d{2}(?:,\d{2})*(?=])', '{"data":[12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90,10], "something": {"key":"value"}}')
['12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,90,10']
```

In Python, the `findall` function returns a list of all the found matches (in this case the list is of length one).